# How to convert number to a future date relative to today

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a number provided by a separate formula, and I need to display that number as a future date.

The number is "the total number of months needed to complete project". At this point in time, it is "1.53" months (a little over a month and a half). 1.53 is based on the number of project hours completed.

I need Excel to display "Feb 24, 2016" instead of "1.53", since that would be approximately 1.53 months from today. Tomorrow, if the 1.53 value has not changed, then the field would display "Feb 25, 2016", and so on.

How can I accomplish this with a formula or a formatting setting?

Comment: Are you assuming 30 days per month?  Could you instead change the formula to give you days?  `=Today()+(30*1.53)`

Comment: If you take a step back, somewhere you have computed the total number of 'project hours completed' and there were subsequent calculations that converted that to the number of days and the days were converted to **1.53** months. Go back to the days and add that to the start date using [WORKDAY.INTL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-A378391C-9BA7-4678-8A39-39611A9BF81D). After the weekends and holidays have been configured into the WORKDAY.INTL, the result will be the prospective end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **A1** contains 1.53, then in another cell enter:

```
=TODAY()+A1*365.25/12
```

and apply the proper format:

[image]